# Json object with array for datasource binding

Tags: .net, arrays, json, c#-4.0

i have data from server API which return JSON object.
i want to bind this data to databindingsource, but one of the data is not showing because it is an int array

this is the JSON object

```
namespace Example
{
    internal class SampleResponse1
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nameDecorated")]
        public string NameDecorated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("externalId")]
        public string ExternalId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("openingDate")]
        public int[] OpeningDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hierarchy")]
        public string Hierarchy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

the problem is the "opening date" which return by the server using integer array, and i need it as a datetime.

please advise to convert this object so i can have the correct type

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does the int array represent a date?

Comment: int[0] = year; int[1] = month; int[2] = day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SampleResponse1
{
    [JsonProperty("openingDate")]
    public int[] Opening{ get; set; }

    public DateTime OpeningDate
    {
        get
        {
            return new DateTime(Opening[0], Opening[1], Opening[2]);
        }
    }
}
```